# Setting up wireless MESH network open 80211s in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to set up a MESH network (OPEN MESH network) using the instructions on [this site](https://github.com/cozybit/open80211s/wiki/HOWTO).

I am using kernel4.4.0-45-generic.

The modification of kernel in Ubuntu is required for MESH network creation or all things are in that kernel already.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what kind of Wifi hardware you are using.

Check `lspci -v` to find out which driver is used for your wireless networking device. Then look for it on https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers and find out it's mesh capability. If it isn't listed there not all is lost though, as the list might be a bit outdated, if I recall correctly.

You may then check via `iw list` if "mesh point" is in the list of "Supported interface modes" for your wifi device. If it is you should be able to create a mesh using the How-To you already found.

If for any reason your device does not report mesh capability but your are very sure it should have it, you can try compile and install an updated version of your devices driver.